# Download a file from the company's SharePoint when Redirect to Okta authentication -python

Tags: python, sharepoint, okta

im trying to use download a file with python script from my company's SharePoint - the problem is that i cannot use "Sharepy" library because - to login to the SharePoint I redirected to Okta login page ( the company is using Okta authentication ), any ideas how can I pass it? I'm trying to use 'requests' without any success, thank you/

this is what I've tried :

```
payload ={
  "username": "*********",
  "password": "*****",
  "relayState": "https://*******.sharepoint.com",
  "options": {
  "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": False,
  "warnBeforePasswordExpired": False,
"
}
  }
rq=requests.Session()
respone = rq.post('https://********.okta.com/api/v1/authn', json=payload)
respone2 = rq.get('https://**************.sharepoint.com')
```

Comment: i believe there should be callback url wherein you get something like auth code or token. please explain your issue in more details including what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to replicate your issue as I don't have any account to test on.
I will suggest to check the 'Network' tab in your browser (FireFox) recommended. Using Dev tools.

1. Open the login URL (your company's sharepoint URL)
2. Hit on login (Keep the network tab open)
3. It should re-direct you to okta login page.
4. Copy the POST request URL.
5. Get all the details including Request headers, payload, response.
6. In response, it will give you kind of auth code / token.
7. Try to use this auth token to send post request to your company's sharepoint site.

Again, please check all the requests under network tab. You have todo R&D.

Comment: how can i know which information i need to pass besides the token?